# How to tell the difference between chat and inbox chat in the new Messages Platform on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I noticed that with the new messages' feature, chat messages seem to be archived (or at least those chat messages sent after activating the new platform). How does one tell the difference between one that was sent via chat window (at the bottom) versus the message inbox.

My current way to sort is by emoticons since friends tend to make emoticons more frequently than a message sent from the Inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kind of works like in Google Wave. If you're both online then if your friend sends you a message, you get a chat conversation and it is archived in your inbox. Regardless of where the message was composed, if both of you are online on chat then the recipient would receive it in the chatbox and the inbox. If one of you is offline, then it would go straight to the inbox.